# What do we know about Hamas’s abuse of the Gazan population?

Tags: armed-conflict, israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, hamas

A [ynetnews.com opinion piece](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/hjimtxj86) reads:

> The claim "ethnic cleansing" also lacks a basis in reality. Those learned academicians base their claim on the removal of civilians in Gaza from the northern areas to the south of the Strip. That is not evidence of an ethnic cleansing, but rather an attempt by the IDF to limit civilian casualties. In their claims, **there is no mention of the humanitarian corridors opened for the population to leave the impacted areas to the safety of the south, even as Hamas snipers were attempting to prevent their escape**. The claim also ignores the aid trucks providing essentials into the Strip daily. **Many of these trucks are robbed by members of Hamas who take their contents to be used by Hamas rather than the civilians for whom the aid was provided. The terrorists also sell the aid back to the Gaza civilians for exorbitant prices although they were meant to be distributed for free.**

What do we know about the Hamas abuse of the Gazan population since October 7? How many Gazans have been executed for their collaboration with Israel, trying to flee from the IDF, or refusing to fight? What fraction of humanitarian supplies has been diverted by Hamas?

Here is a more specific report:

[Video likely shows Gaza civilians shot by Hamas as they were trying to evacuate to safety](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/ryjyna7qa)

Some more recent claims of abuses (but all from Ynetnews, so independent confirmations would be useful):

- ['Honestly, I prefer the IDF': Palestinians in Gaza speak out on Hamas abuse](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/b1adtde006?utm_source=taboola&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=internal)
- [Palestinian security official shot for calling Hamas 'Iranian proxy'](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/sjfgjbbwt?utm_source=taboola&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=internal) (this one actually took place in the West Bank)

(I appreciate using multiple sources, so that the information could be verified.)

Comment: Voting to close... There are multiple, impossibly broad questions here. You want a summary of all the reporting on the human rights and corruption issues? Please do some preliminary research and narrow it down.

Comment: @BrianZ a report by a pro-Palestinian group would suffice - they are surely concerned about this.

Comment: @RogerV. The question is mostly based on a quote from this opinion piece, the credibility of which has yet to be established. In particular the claims that you emphasize in bold are not sourced either, and they are questionable. It's also unclear what the additional link is showing, no mainstream news appears to confirm the claim.

Comment: @Erwan precisely, I am trying to verify correctness of these claims. However, I also added the link to the video, on the basis of which the claims are made.

Comment: If you're trying to verify the correctness perhaps this is better aimed at the skeptics SE?

Comment: Under martial law, most of civilian possessions may be confiscated at will if they are needed to fight the war. Since there's an IDF-Hamas war, I don't see why Hamas taking anything they want off civilian trucks will raise any eyebrows.

Comment: If you are reading some non-Israeli sources as well, you should know that there is no 'safety of the south', the IDF bombed all parts of the Gaza strip. The aid trucks entering Gaza are limited by Israel and the total quantities of food and water available are nowhere near enough to supply the population of Gaza. What little there is may be badly distributed by Hamas but it is Israels choice that the total amount of food available causes the current famine in Gaza.

Comment: @quarague the question is about Hamas - they also need to be held responsible for their crimes against the Palestinian people. They brought this unnecessary war upon Gazans.

Comment: @quarague, "The current famine in Gaza" - Any pictures of skeletons? Israel is currently allowing into Gaza about 200 trailers per day. I'm not an expert on food rations, so I'm unable to determine if 1 trailer of food per day per 10,000 people is enough to keep them healthy, although a trailer can certainly take much more than 10,000 kilograms of food (each cubic meter of grains or flour is 1,000 kilograms). The assertion that Gaza is currently in a "famine", even without Hamas stealing the food supplies, needs more proof.

Comment: @Jacob3 Here is the UN coming to that conclusion: https://www.unicef.org/press-releases/statement-unicef-risk-famine-gaza-strip

Comment: @quarague, Ok, a biased organization warning about a "risk" that a famine "might" develop, and that many people are in "food insecurity", which means that their food source is not stable. Although being a very unfortunate condition, That's not a famine.

Comment: @Jacob3 If you don't trust the UN I can't help you with that, but from their report "The report also said that almost 1.2 million people are experiencing emergency levels of acute food insecurity and acknowledged that famine thresholds for acute food insecurity have already been exceeded. In short, this means for many families in Gaza, the threat of dying from hunger is already real." They are not saying there may be a risk, they are saying people are currently suffering from hunger and have a real risk of starving.

Comment: @quarague, Again "food insecurity" does not mean hunger, just like general "insecurity" doesn't mean death.

Comment: The lack of independent foreign journalism in Gaza (due primarily to Israel, which has barred journalists from entering Gaza) means it is unlikely we will have answers to your questions.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 please cite the sources for your claim.

Comment: **Voting to keep open.** The stated close reason in incorrect: *"Opinion-based: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers."* There are multiple citations supporting the answers. Some citations are even included in the OP.